# Ubuntu blinks in DELL 2850

Tags: ubuntu, dell-poweredge

I have just installed Ubuntu (12.0.4 TLS for Servers) on a DELL poweredge 2850. During the installation, the process goes OK. However, as soon as I start the system normally (and the text font is changed) it starts continuously blinking: 4 seconds I can see the screen, 4 seconds is black, and so on and so forth. This annoying behaviour does not happen during installation or if I run x-windows. Any ideas of what could be happening?

PS: I have asked in Ask-Ubuntu (https://askubuntu.com/questions/314771/ubuntu-blinks-in-dell-2850) and have been redirected here

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might have an issue where your monitor's autodetection is kicking in inappropriately.  Many monitors will second-guess themselves and do things like constantly switch the active input for no reason or display "input out of range" overtop of an otherwise properly displayed image when they receive a signal or EDID data that confuses them.

Try explicitly passing the `vga` option to your kernel.  For instance, for 1280x1024 24bpp, specify `vga=795`.  Alternatively, replace the monitor.

Occasionally I have also seen this problem caused by a bad video card or display cable.

Comment: mmm.. I am trying to do this but with any parameter I pass on to vga on grub I got a "xxx vga mode is deprecated". I do not have time to read the rest...